# Laravel composer update give error

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

I just update the compose and i found below error.

> php artisan clear-compiled PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler::directive() in
>   /var/www/html/innomaid/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php
>   on line 213
>
> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>   Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler::directive()

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error

> [RuntimeException]
>   Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler::directive() in
>   /var/www/html/innomaid/ve
>   ndor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on
>   line 213

Here is my composer code

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
        "illuminate/html": "5.*",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.6.*",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*",
        "gloudemans/shoppingcart": "~1.3",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3"

    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
        "zizaco/entrust": "dev-laravel-5"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve this error

Comment: try change "illuminate/html": "5.*", with this "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0", and let me know

Comment: #maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ Not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update `"zizaco/entrust": "dev-laravel-5"` to `"zizaco/entrust": "1.4.1"`

Solve my problem.

Comment: check it as answered